# RavenDB 4.0 - InMemoryDatabase - EmbeddableDocumentStore

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

I am trying to migrate to new `RavenDb 4.0`, old code for tests purposes was using `EmbeddableDocumentStore` from the NuGet package: `RavenDB.Database`.

Usage:

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
               {
                   RunInMemory = true
               };
               documentStore.Configuration.Storage.Voron.AllowOn32Bits = true;
               documentStore.Initialize();
```

I can't find that or simillar class in `RavenDB 4.0` though, is there any kind of new approach to test the raven-dependent code?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RavenDB 4.0, all operations goes through the HTTP pipeline.

Basically you will be able to setup a store using https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v4.0/test/Tests.Infrastructure/TestBase.cs `GetNewServer` and there you have a `runInMemory` boolean.

Later edit: As Ayende Rahien said below it can be used via `Raven.TestDriver` package.

You'll need to setup a server, connect to it and run tests on that instance.

Comment: Is that `TesBase.cs` class a part of `RavenDb.Server` package? Or even if that sth I should try to create for my tests, is `RavenDB.Server` available for v4.0? or I should still use `RavenDb.Server` 3.5 and should be compatible?

Comment: `TestBase` isn't part of `RavenDB.Server` package. You should try to create something like this on your own. You have access to`4.0.0-rc-40019` `RavenDB.Server` but just as a zip https://ravendb.net/download#server/dev. I don't think that you can use `RavenDB.Server 3.5` package.

Comment: Alright, it's just the fact Raven4 is not yet ready. I hope that will be a package at some point, and most of the problems will go away. 

Anyway, I will stop now trying to use it, and come back to it maybe later. Thank you for response.

Comment: You can use that through `Raven.TestDriver` package.

Comment: @RazvanDumitru would you please check my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746610/raven-client-exceptions-database-databasedoesnotexistexception-database

Comment: @AyendeRahien would you please check my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746610/raven-client-exceptions-database-databasedoesnotexistexception-database