# Raven.Client.Exceptions.Database.DatabaseDoesNotExistException: 'Database '*****' does not exist

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, ravendb, raventestdriver

I am using `RavenTestDriver` for my .net core unit tests .
Here is my configuration of my `RavenTestDriver` in my unit test solution :

```
public class TestHostBuilder : RavenTestDriver, IAsyncLifetime
    {


        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {

            ConfigureServer(new TestServerOptions
            {

                CommandLineArgs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "--RunInMemory=true", },
                FrameworkVersion = null,
            });

            var hostBuilder = easy.api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0])
         .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
         {
             webHostBuilder.UseTestServer();
         })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
               services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, InitRequest>();
                services.AddRavenDbAsyncSession(GetDocumentStore());
                services.AddScoped<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
            {
                return GetDocumentStore().OpenAsyncSession(new SessionOptions()
                {
                    Database="test-server"
                });
                });
        });

            var host = hostBuilder.Start();
        }

    }
```

But when I call my Repository to get the object I get this error :

```
Database 'test-server' does not exist.'
   at Raven.Client.Exceptions.Database.DatabaseDoesNotExistException.Throw(String databaseName) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Exceptions\Database\DatabaseDoesNotExistException.cs:line 35
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__114`1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 883
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__114`1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 900
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<UpdateTopologyAsync>d__101.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 455
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<FirstTopologyUpdate>d__109.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 678
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<WaitForTopologyUpdate>d__107.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 613
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Http.RequestExecutor.<UnlikelyExecuteAsync>d__106`1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Http\RequestExecutor.cs:line 583
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.AsyncDocumentSession.<LoadAsync>d__51`1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.3\53009\src\Raven.Client\Documents\Session\AsyncDocumentSession.Load.cs:line 30
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at infrastructure.Persistence.RavenDb.RavenRepository`1.<GetByIdAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in D:\gitProjects\Orbis\infrastructure\Persistence\RavenDb\RavenRepository.cs:line 83
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at infrastructure.ApplicationCache.CacheableRepository`1.<GetAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in D:\gitProjects\Orbis\infrastructure\ApplicationCache\CacheableRepository.cs:line 48
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at easy.api.Application.Setting.Queries.GetClientAppSettingQueryHandler.<Handle>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\gitProjects\**\***\Application\Setting\Queries\GetClientAppSettingQuery.cs:line 35
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at api.common.Behaviors.UnhandledExceptionBehaviour`2.<Handle>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\gitProjects\**\api.common\Behaviors\UnhandledExceptionBehaviour.cs:line 22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the database before calling `OpenAsyncSession`
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/csharp/client-api/operations/server-wide/create-database#example

Comment: Thank you it works .I just added this part to my init method : try
            {
                store.Maintenance.ForDatabase("test-server").Send(new GetStatisticsOperation());
            }
            catch (DatabaseDoesNotExistException)
            {
                try
                {
                    store.Maintenance.Server.Send(new CreateDatabaseOperation(new DatabaseRecord("test-server")));
                }
                catch (ConcurrencyException)
                {

                }

            }

Comment: In particular, _why_ are you defining the db name yourself of the test?
If you leave that out completely, the `RavenTestDriver` will do everything for you. Which will later allow you to do things like safely run the tests in parallel.

Comment: @AyendeRahien I didn't know that .I deleted database name in my configuration .Thanks Dear friend Ayende

Comment: @AyendeRahien When I removed database name from configuration I got several errors :  System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred ---- System.AggregateException-------- System.AggregateException------------ System.AggregateException---------------- System.AggregateException    -------------------- Akka.Remote.RemoteTransportException : Failed to bind to [0.0.0.0:3215]. See InnerException for details.    ------------------------ System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.Why?

Comment: I asked another question that you mentioned .I set fixed database name and I faced with this error :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751129/ravendb-the-database-is-currently-locked-because-checking-if-we-need-to-rec

Comment: You are calling `GetDocumentStore()` multiple times, getting _different_ instances.

Comment: @AyendeRahien would you please take a look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159272/set-address-and-port-of-raventestdriver-in-static-in-net-core